# Call JavaScript's setTimeOut in dojo Class

Tags: javascript, dojo, settimeout

I'm trying to convert my JavaScript functions to a dojo Class. I've a `setTimeOut("functionName",2000)` in one of my JS method. How do I call this from a method in the class decared using dojo.declare method. For example, below is my custom class.

```
    dojo.declare("Person",null,{
                    constructor:function(age,country,name,state){
                        this.age=age;
                        this.country=country;
                        this.name=name;
                        this.state=state;
                    },
                    moveToNewState:function(newState){
                        this.state=newState;
//I need to call "isStateChanged" method after 2000 ms. How do I do this?
                        setTimeOut("isStateChanged",2000);
                    },                  
                    isStateChanged:function(){
                        alert('state is updated');
                    }
                });
var person=new Person(12,"US","Test","TestState");
person.moveToNewState("NewState");
```

Please let me know how I can call `isStateChanged` method from `moveToNewState` method after 2000ms.

Comment: It's `setTimeout`, not `setTimeOut`, and it's best (always, or almost always) to pass it a function reference, not a string it has to compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is a way of *binding* the `this` value to the function that `setTimeout` will call:

```
moveToNewState:function(newState){
    // Remember `this` in a variable within this function call
    var context = this;

    // Misc logic
    this.state = newState;

    // Set up the callback
    setTimeout(function() {
        // Call it
        context.isStateChanged();
    }, 2000);
},
```

The above is using a *closure* to bind the context (see: [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)), which is the usual way to do this. Dojo may offer a built-in function for generating these "bound" callbacks (Prototype and jQuery do). (**Edit:** It does, in his comment below [peller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153101/peller) kindly pointed out [`dojo.hitch`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo.hitch).)

More about this general concept here: [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It worked. Why are we creating a new variable called context  and then assigning the current object to it? I thought "this" will refer to "Person" object and it has got a method "isStateChanged"

Comment: @Steven: *"Why are we creating a new variable called context and then assigning the current object to it?"* Because `this` (in JavaScript) is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not *where a function is defined*. `setTimeout` calls the function in the global context, which on browsers means `this` will be `window`, which obviously isn't want you want. More in the *[You must remember `this`](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html)* link above, as well as here: *[Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*

Comment: The closure is actually not necessary in this case, but [dojo.hitch](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo.hitch) is Dojo's equivalent for binding variables.

Comment: @peller: Ah, there you go, thanks. I knew Dojo would have one. Remember that there's a closure involved regardless, it's just a matter of what it closes over -- jQuery's `proxy`, Prototype's `bind`, and Dojo's `hitch` will all create closures, but they do it in a nice, well-contained scope within the library code so the closure isn't unnecessarily keeping anything additional in memory.

Comment: +1  True, a closure must be involved, at least if you want to reference 'this' within the called function.  Sorry I realized my down votes were hasty.  Stack overflow didn't let me undo them :-/  FWIW, now ES5 also has bind.

Comment: @peller: I keep forgetting that ECMAScript 5 added `Function#bind`, thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with dojo, this is pure javascript. What you're looking for is:

```
var $this = this;
setTimeout(function() { $this.isStateChanged() }, 2000);
```

Check out [the docs on setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Oh, and, please don't use quotes around your function names (because that makes it a useless string that will probably get `eval`ed and will give an error).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It worked. Why are we creating a new variable called $this and then assigning the current object to it? I thought "this" will refer to "Person" object and it has got a method "isStateChanged"

Comment: `this` does refer to the `Person` instance, but only in the `moveToNewState` closure. When the timeout is fired, it's context (read: the `this` magic variable) will not be the `Person` instance, but to `window`. This is why you need to store the instance in a differently-named variable. **T.J. Crowder** posted some good links about this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much Felix for your kind reply

Answer (score 2):

You could simply call `setTimeout(this.isStateChanged, 2000)` which will pass the correct function reference, not unlike the way you would call the method directly.  The expression `this.isStateChanged` is evaluated immediately.  To make the call, there's no need to wrap it in an extra function or declare local variables.

To bind the `this` variable to the called function, you can use [dojo.hitch](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/dojo.hitch) which will create its own closure without polluting the local variable space and potentially leaking through other references.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dojo/_base/lang and use its hitch method like the below code:

```
moveToNewState:function(newState){
  // Misc logic
  this.state = newState;

  // Set up the callback
  setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, function() {
    // Call with `this`
    this.isStateChanged();
  }), 2000);
},
```